# Algorithm for converting an input sequence into a list array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

This is my code:

```
$arr = array([], [], []);
function show() {
  $numbers = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
  $value = []; 
  while (count($numbers) > 0){     
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
      array_push($value, $numbers[$i]);
      array_push($arr[$i], $numbers[$i]);
    }
    $numbers = array_diff($numbers, $value);
    echo count($numbers);
    $value = [];
  }
}

show();
print_r($arr)
```

I want to specify the numbers for three empty arrays in `$arr` above, but need to iterate over each empty array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )
     .......
)
```

My problem is the while loop, it runs forever and doesn't stop.

The expected output after running the function `show()` is:

```
$arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were getting infinite loop because numbers arrays was never becoming zero, instead keep a count of its length and decrement it at the end of each step

```
<?php


  function show(){
$arr = array();
  $numbers = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
  $value  = array(); 
$c=count($numbers);
  while( $c > 0){     
    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
if(!isset($arr[$i])){
$arr[$i]=array();
}
      array_push($value,$numbers[$i]);
      array_push($arr[$i],$numbers[$i]);
    }
$c=$c-1;
     $numbers=array_diff($numbers,$value);
     $c= count($numbers);
      $value = [];
   
}
 return $arr;
 }
    print_r(show());
   

?>
```

Your comment requirement, use `array_chunk()`

```
<?php
  function show(){
$arr = array();
  $numbers = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
return array_chunk($numbers, 3); 

 }
    print_r(show());
```

enjoy!

Comment: sorry there is confution expected, i want to output is :  $arr= [ [1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8] ]  can you help me?